# Swift fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, i don't know why

Tags: ios, swift

I was crashed at this code i don't know why.

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
I has imported MobileCoreServices and follow this spotlight framework [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/core-spotlight-framework/).

```
var moviesInfo : NSMutableArray!    
func setupSearchableContent() {
        var searchableItems = [CSSearchableItem]()

        for i in 0...(moviesInfo.count - 1) {

            let movie = moviesInfo[i] as! [String: String]
            let searchableItemAttributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet(itemContentType: kUTTypeText as String)

            //set the title
            searchableItemAttributeSet.title = movie["Title"]!

            //set the image
            let imagePathParts = movie["Image"]!.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
            searchableItemAttributeSet.thumbnailURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(imagePathParts[0], withExtension: imagePathParts[1])

            // Set the description.
            searchableItemAttributeSet.contentDescription = movie["Description"]!

            var keywords = [String]()
            let movieCategories = movie["Category"]!.componentsSeparatedByString(", ")
            for movieCategory in movieCategories {
                keywords.append(movieCategory)
            }

            let stars = movie["Stars"]!.componentsSeparatedByString(", ")
            for star in stars {
                keywords.append(star)
            }

            searchableItemAttributeSet.keywords = keywords

            let searchableItem = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier: "com.appcoda.SpotIt.\(i)", domainIdentifier: "movies", attributeSet: searchableItemAttributeSet)

            searchableItems.append(searchableItem)

            CSSearchableIndex.defaultSearchableIndex().indexSearchableItems(searchableItems) { (error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

[image: the crash line]

Comment: This is the most asked question on the whole of stackoverflow. Search for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is the `moviesInfo` array is `nil`, when you accessed it.

You can fix it in two ways:

#### #1

Change the array declaration to

```
var moviesInfo = NSMutableArray()
```

#### #2

Use conditional unwrapping

```
func setupSearchableContent()
{
    var searchableItems = [CSSearchableItem]()

    guard let movieInfo = moviesInfo else
    {
       return
    }

    for i in 0...(movieInfo.count - 1)
    {
      // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `moviesInfo` as empty Swift `Array`, then it could never be nil

```
var moviesInfo = [[String:String]]()
```

Using a strong type you can further replace

```
for i in 0...(moviesInfo.count - 1) {
let movie = moviesInfo[i] as! [String: String]
```

with

```
for (i, movie) in moviesInfo.enumerate() {
```